# Stack in C: why do i have memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

just revising C here. I just ran valgrind and it turns out i have memory leaks in my program, even though i free the memory i allocate. What am i missing?

stack.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

struct node {
  int element;
  Node *next;
};

struct stack {
  Node *tos;
};

Stack *stack_create() {
  Stack *S;
  if ((S = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack))) != NULL)
      S->tos = NULL;
  return S;
}

void stack_destroy(Stack *S) {
  Node *temp = S->tos;
  while (S->tos != NULL) {
    temp = S->tos;
    free(S->tos);
    S->tos = temp->next;
  }
  free(S);
}

void push(Stack *S, int element) {
  Node *N;
  if ((N = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node))) != NULL) {
    N->element = element;
    N->next = (S->tos == NULL) ? NULL : S->tos;
    S->tos = N;
  }
}

int pop(Stack *S) {
  Node *tos = S->tos;
  S->tos = tos->next;  
  return (int) tos->element;
}

int peek(Stack *S) {
  return (int) S->tos->element;
}

void to_string(Stack *S) {
  Node *cursor = S->tos;
  while (cursor != NULL) {
    printf("[%d] ", cursor->element);
    cursor = cursor->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}


int main() 
{
  Stack *S;

  S = stack_create();

  push(S, 5);
  push(S, 6);
  push(S, 4);
  push(S, -55);

  to_string(S);

  printf("Pop %d\n", pop(S));
  printf("Pop %d\n", pop(S));

  to_string(S);

  stack_destroy(S);

  return 0;  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe its too obvious, but I'm pretty sure you just need to change your "stack_destroy".  You free "S->tos" before saving "S->tos->next".

Comment: Why don't you include the valgrind output?

Comment: in stack_destroy, instead of temp call it Node* next;  then next = S->tos->next;   then  s->tos = next;  that way you aren't referencing free'd memory, though this isn't your problem

Comment: Because valgrind is in the VM. Can't copy the output

Answer (score 2):

the actual problem is your Pop kills the node, but it doesn't free it

```
Node* node_destroy(Node* n)

    Node* next;
    if(n == NULL) return NULL;
    next = n->next;
    free(n);
    return next;
}


int stack_pop(Stack *s) {
      int element;
      if(s == NULL || s->tos == NULL) return 0;  // no really good result you can give
      element = s->tos->element;    
      s->tos = node_destroy(s->tos);
      return element;
    }
```

then you can do

```
void stack_destroy(Stack *S) {
  while (S->tos != NULL) {
    s->tos = node_destroy(s->tos);
  }
  free(S);
}
```

Comment: Oh true, i just dereference it and that'it - it is lost

Comment: you'll also need to think about providing a `is_stack_empty` function, because the pop is odd if if you pop an empty stack

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your destroy method. You free `S->tos` which temp refers to. Then you use `temp->next`.

set temp to `S->tos->next`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your destory:

```
void stack_destroy(Stack *S) {
  Node *temp = S->tos;
  while (S->tos != NULL) {
    temp = S->tos;
    free(S->tos);
    S->tos = temp->next;
  }
  free(S);
}
```

Temp is pointing to `S->tos` from:

```
temp = S->tos;
```

But then you immediately free it after:

```
free(S->tos);
```

Then when you call the `temp->next;` temp is already freed.

Try this:

```
void stack_destroy(Stack *S) {
  Node *temp; //Also, no need to assign here from the original (you assign to it immediately within the while)
  while (S->tos != NULL) {
    temp = S->tos->next; //You need to get the pointer to node "next" before you free S->tos
    free(S->tos);
    S->tos = temp;
  }
  free(S);
}
```

EDIT1:  Per [Keith Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431/keith-nicholas) - [See here for his elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21865024/1366973)

Pop also does not free the node you extract the element from:

old:

```
int pop(Stack *S) {
  Node *tos = S->tos;
  S->tos = tos->next;  
  return (int) tos->element;
}
```

new:

```
int pop(Stack *S) {
  Node *tos = S->tos;
  int element = tos->element;
  S->tos = tos->next;  
  free(tos);
  return element;
}
```

Comment: except you don't need the first assignment

Comment: just Node *temp; is fine

Comment: Nice catch!  I edited that as well as added a useful comment.

Comment: I'd probably take the inner of the loop and extract a function  Node* node_destroy(Node* n);  which returns the next or NULL if there isn't a next.  the stack_destroy is `while(S->tos != null) s->tos = node_destroy(S->tos); free(S);`

Comment: updated the code with a screenshot. still 16 bytes lost

Comment: Keith Nicholas has a more elegant solution, but I updated mine to be inclusive as well.